# RxJS: How to create an event manager with a buffer that flush based on multiple conditions

Tags: rxjs

I have a requirement to create an event manager with a buffer that flushes if one of 3 criteria is met:

1. 2 seconds pass
2. 50 events received
3. Flush on demand if requested by user

All criteria will reset when buffer flushes (reset the 2 second timer, reset the 50 events count...etc)

This is what I've implemeted so far and it seems to be working but I'm wondering if there's a better way to achieve this requirement.

```js
import { interval, merge, Subject, Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { bufferWhen, filter, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

class Foo {
  private eventListener: Subject < string > = new Subject();
  private eventForceFlushListener: Subject < void > = new Subject();
  private eventBufferSizeListener: Subject < void > = new Subject();
  private maxBufferSize = 50;
  private currentBufferSize = 0;



  /**
   * 
   * Buffer that will flush if one of the 3 criteria is met:
   * - 50 texts are received
   * - 2 seconds pass
   * - Force flush by user
   */
  private eventBufferOperator = () => merge(interval(2 * 1000), this.eventForceFlushListener, this.eventBufferSizeListener);

  /**
   * Flush buffer if requested by user. (for example flush buffer before app close so we dont lose buffered texts)
   */
  public forceFlush() {
    this.eventForceFlushListener.next();
  }

  /**
   * Method used by users to emit texts to the listener 
   */
  public emitText(text: string) {
    this.eventListener.next(text);
    this.currentBufferSize = this.currentBufferSize + 1;
    if (this.currentBufferSize == this.maxBufferSize) {
      // flush all evenst when maxBufferSize is reached
      this.eventBufferSizeListener.next();
      // buffer size is reset below in the function that's inside "subscribe"
    }
  }

  public subscribeToEventListerenr() {
    const eventListenerSubscription = this.eventListener
      .pipe(
        tap((text) => text.trim()),
        filter((text) => true),
        bufferWhen(this.eventBufferOperator),
        filter((events) => !!events.length)
      )
      .subscribe((x) => {
        console.log(x);
        this.maxBufferSize = 0; // reset size buffer
      });

    return eventListenerSubscription;
  }
}
```

Users then can use this event manager as follows:

```js
    const eventManager = new Foo();
    eventManager.subscribeToEventListerenr();
    eventManager.emitText('message1');
    eventManager.emitText('message2');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. 5 seconds pass
2. 5 events received
3. Flush on demand if requested by user

```js
const { race, Subject, take, share, buffer, tap, bufferCount, bufferTime, startWith, exhaustMap, map } = rxjs;

const observer = (str) => ({
  subscribe: () => console.log(`${str} -> subscribe`),
  next: () => console.log(`${str} -> next`),
  unsubscribe: () => console.log(`${str} -> unsubscribe`),
});

const event$ = new Subject()
const share$ = event$.pipe(map((_, i) => i + 1), share());
const flush$ = new Subject();

const trigger$ = flush$.pipe(tap(observer('flush$')));
const bufferSize$ = share$.pipe(startWith(null), bufferCount(5), tap(observer('BufferSize 5')));
const bufferTime$ = share$.pipe(bufferTime(5000), tap(observer('5 Sec')));

const race$ = race(bufferTime$, trigger$, bufferSize$).pipe(take(1));
const buffer$ = share$.pipe(exhaustMap(() => race$));

share$.pipe(buffer(buffer$)).subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.6/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="event$.next()">event</button>
<button onclick="flush$.next()">flush</button>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-5qgaeq

Comment: Thanks Eddy. Do all buffers here get reset whenever flush is triggered?

Comment: I changes the behavior, you can try it.It will start buffer after has value, and always reset

Answer (score 0):

**My final answer**

- [window](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/window)
- [bufferTime](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/bufferTime)

```js
const bufferBy$ = new Subject<void>();
const maxBufferSize = 3;
const bufferTimeSpan = 5000;

source$.pipe(
  window(bufferBy$),
  mergeMap(bufferTime(bufferTimeSpan, null, maxBufferSize)),
).subscribe(...);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-hoafkr